# Flotcharts not rendering with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, flot, angularjs-service

I am having issues rendering Flotcharts with data populated from an AngularJS (v1.2.5) service call. When the data is hard-coded, the charts render as expected but not when assigned the value from a $resource call (console logging shows "undefined" as the value).

The odd thing is that the same variable I use to populate the chart data is displayed in the view and works fine which makes me think this could be some sort of race condition or scoping issue.

I have tried assigning the the $scope variables as a result of resolved promises without success to remedy race conditions as well as tried things such as $scope.$apply() from the chart directive.

Below are code excerpts from my application. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

HTML wrapper:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="app">
    <head>
        <title>FlotChart Example</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <main data-ng-view></main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Template from Overview route:

```
<div class="chart-title">{{getCount.count}} Total Transactions</div>
<div id="deposits" data-chart="pie" data-flot-chart data-ng-model="model" data-ng-controller="OverviewCtrl"></div>
```

Main Module ("app"):

```
;(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngTouch', 'services.Localization', 'Login', 'Overview'])
        .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
                controller: 'LoginCtrl'
            })
            .when('/overview', {
                templateUrl: 'views/overview.html',
                controller: 'OverviewCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
        }])

        .controller('App', ['$rootScope', 'Localize', function ($rootScope, Localize) {
            // initialize localization
            $rootScope.labels = Localize.get();
        }]);
}(angular));
```

Overview Controller (used in charts and view):

```
;(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('Overview', ['services.DepositsSvc'])

        .controller('OverviewCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'DepositCount', 'DepositCountGET', function ($rootScope, $scope, DepositCount, DepositCountGET) {

            $scope.getCount = DepositCount.get();

            $scope.getGETCount = DepositCountGET.get();

            $scope.model = {};

            $scope.model.data = [
                {
                    label: $rootScope.labels.gets,
                    data: $scope.getGETCount.count,
                    color: "#e4d672"
                },
                {
                    label: $rootScope.labels.puts,
                    data: $scope.getCount.count,
                    color: "#c2cfeb"
                }
            ];

            $scope.model.options = {
                series: {
                    pie: {
                        show: true,
                        radius: 1,
                        label: {
                            radius: 2/3,
                            formatter: function (label, series) {
                                return '<div class="pie">' + label + ': ' +
                                    series.data[0][1] + '<br>(' + Math.round(series.percent) + '%)</div>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    show: false
                }
            };
        }]);
}(angular));
```

Services (output from both calls is { count: number }):

```
;(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('services.DepositsSvc', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute'])

        .factory('DepositCount', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
            return $resource('/rest/deposits/count', {}, {
                query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }
            });
        }])

        .factory('DepositCountGET', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
            return $resource('/rest/deposits/countgetdeposits', {}, {
                query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }
            });
        }]);
}(angular));
```

Charts directive:

```
;(function (angular, $) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('directives.FlotCharts', [])

        .directive('flotChart', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                controller: ['$scope', '$attrs', function ($scope, $attrs) {
                    var plotid = '#' + $attrs.id,
                        model = $scope[$attrs.ngModel];

                    $scope.$watch('model', function (x) {
                        $.plot(plotid, x.data, x.options);
                    });
                }]
            };
        });
}(angular, jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution documented at [AngularJS Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/lShQMt0jMK4).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to distill this down to a smaller example that fits in a jsFiddle, so we can try it out.

One thing that I notice, though, is that you're doing a shallow watch, then setting model.data and model.options.  So unless I'm missing something, the watch will not fire when those change; only when model itself changes.  Try passing `true` as the third argument to watch.

Comment: Thanks. I'll work on a jsFiddle for this issue. Adding `true` as the third option to didn't work in my existing implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that would solve your problem (because this maybe the result of numerous problem) but I think you got the directive scope and model attachment wrong:

*. I'm not sure why you encapsulate the directive as a self invoking function (never saw this style before, and Sure it isn't needed.

*. you are creating a new module here with the `('directives.flotCharts',[])` syntax, without the `[]` you could attach the directive to any existing module. **the important part** is that this module isn't injected into app! you should include it in the `app` module dependency array. without it, angular doesn't know about this directive (and also include the js file in index.html... I sometimes forget and wonder why is this not working) 
*. I would suggest rewriting the directive as (and notice the comments also):
something like this:

```
angular.module('directives.FlotCharts', []) // creaating a new module here
    .directive('flotChart', function () {
        return {o
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope:{model:"=ngModel"},//creating a two ways binding to ngModel
            controller: ['$scope', '$attrs','$element', function ($scope, $attrs,$element) {
                var plotid = '#' + $attrs.id, // you are doing an ugly hack instead of using $element, which comes with the directive, $element is a jquery (or jquery lite) object (if you included jQuery **before** angular.js in index.html it is a jQuery object)


                    $scope.$watch(function(){return $scope.model}, function (x) {
                        if (!x){
                           return;
                        }
                        $.plot(plotid, x.data, x.options);//may need to wrap this in an $apply, depends.. //surly this should be called on the $element object - something like: $element.plot(x.data, x.options) although I don't now the specifics of this lib.
                    }, true); //the true is needed for a deep equality and not just shallow check, which sometimes has problems with objects.. not sure you need this here.
                }]
            };
        });
```

I also suspect you are treating promises wrong. but not sure this is the problem here (although when everything else would work this probabely could and would be a problem. to scope this answer and question I think you should refine the promises issue to a different and specific question.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'm working on a jsFiddle for this issue as it is not working from feedback.

Regarding questions/comments:
* Using IIFE because of strict mode and passing in angularjs & jquery objects

* Created as a separate module to inject in several other modules; wanted this to be stand-alone

* Rewrote directive utilizing $element instead of jquery hack.

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulmc/H6Y5c/24/) added. I've stripped down the code even more than what is presented in this thread. Finding that setting hard-coded values for charting is not working in the fiddle but does locally. I am loading all JS dependencies from CDNs except for my code (pasted in the fiddle) and Flot Charts code (from raw github).

Comment: @paul first - let's fix the fiddle. if you open the console, you'll see error messages all over the place, at least the first two can be fixed as **[described](http://geekdave.com/2013/06/19/linking-raw-github-files-from-jsfiddle/) here**. - solving the github.raw problem that breaks the flot chart

Comment: thank you. I have the github issues resolved and created a custom get method for the service since my server is local. Having issues creating external json files that contain data for this item from github [jsfiddle documentation](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/github_response.html#github-response).

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulmc/H6Y5c/28/)

Comment: the updated fiddle is still broit console after saving to make sure this errors are solved.. without it we can't be sure what the problem is. I also would like to suggest  a small fix (partly illustrated in my answer and in my [forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alonisser/fFKW6/1/)) use a function to return the scope.model to watch instead of a string, and try to wrap the call to flotchart in a $timeout, maybe that would do the trick

Comment: I forgot to update with [baselined URL](http://jsfiddle.net/paulmc/H6Y5c/). The issue I'm having is with the instructions for how to use github to house json file for async response. From the current fiddle, I can spoof a response directly from the service instead of making a resource call. This has always been the case. I attempted to use the watch callbacks provided in your fiddle w/out success.

Comment: The more I thought about it and read through the documentation, it may make more sense to use $http instead of $resource because these are GET-only requests. I set up a local node server that returns the object but still having issues. Not sure if I can provide a better fiddle until I can actually return values via async call. Any ideas?

Thank you.